# Plotly Dash Pandas index and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to launch this code into plotly dash but there is an error with regards to the groupby, specifically how the dataframe is grouped and then x and y values of the px.scatter. From I what I understand, it could be the groupby reducing the number of observation such that the x and y are not equal or perhaps the groupby is incorrect.
Any help is much appreciated.

I  ran it on jupyter notebook and got this error ,*Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of [0] but received: Wallclock*

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Wallclock": pd.date_range(
            "22-dec-2020 00:01:36", freq="5min", periods=2000
        ),
        "tcd": np.linspace(3434, 3505, 2000) *np.random.uniform(.9,1.1, 2000),
        "humidity": np.linspace(63, 96, 2000),
    }
).pipe(lambda d: d.assign(Capsule_ID=(d.index // (len(d)//16))+2100015))


import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px  # (version 4.7.0)
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

import openpyxl
import dash  # (version 1.12.0) pip install dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash


app = JupyterDash(__name__)


df = pd.read_excel("tcd vs rh 2.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")

capsuleID = df["Capsule_ID"].unique()
# print(capsuleID)

capsuleID_names = sorted(list(capsuleID))
# print(capsuleID_names)

capsuleID_names_1 = [{"label": k, "value": k} for k in sorted(capsuleID)]
capsuleID_names_2 = [{"label": "(Select All)", "value": "All"}]
capsuleID_names_all = capsuleID_names_1 + capsuleID_names_2

def slider_fig(df):
    return px.scatter(
                df.groupby("Wallclock", as_index=False).size(), x="Wallclock", y="size"
            ).update_layout(
                xaxis={"rangeslider": {"visible": True}, "title":None},
                height=125,
                yaxis={"tickmode": "array", "tickvals": [], "title": None},
                margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
            )

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Relative Humidity vs TCD", style={"text-align": "center"}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="capsule_select",
            options=capsuleID_names_all,
            optionHeight=25,
            multi=True,
            searchable=True,
            placeholder="Please select...",
            clearable=True,
            value=["All"],
            style={"width": "100%"},
        ),
        dcc.Graph(
            id="slider",
            figure=slider_fig(df),
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Graph(id="the_graph"),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)

# -----------------------------------------------------------
@app.callback(
    Output("the_graph", "figure"),
    Output("capsule_select", "value"),
    Output("slider", "figure"),
    Input("capsule_select", "value"),
    Input('slider', 'relayoutData'),
    State("slider", "figure")
)
def update_graph(capsule_chosen, slider, sfig):
    dropdown_values = capsule_chosen

    if "All" in capsule_chosen:
        dropdown_values = capsuleID_names
        dff = df
    else:
        dff = df[
            df["Capsule_ID"].isin(capsule_chosen)
        ]  # filter all rows where capsule ID is the capsule ID selected

    
    if slider and "xaxis.range" in slider.keys():
        dff = dff.loc[dff["Wallclock"].between(*slider["xaxis.range"])]
    else:
        # update slider based on selected capsules
        sfig = slider_fig(dff)
        
    scatterplot = px.scatter(
        data_frame=dff,
        x="tcd",
        y="humidity",
        hover_name="Wallclock",
    )

    scatterplot.update_traces(textposition="top center")

    return scatterplot, dropdown_values, sfig


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #     app.run_server(debug=True)
    app.run_server(mode="inline")
```

Comment: I am able to display the two graphs in my environment (plotly:5.2.2,jupyterlab:3.0.16,Dash:1.21.0). You may want to consider upgrading.

Comment: Hi, I tried running after updating and that error is gone. However, I have received this `callback() takes from 3 to 5 positional arguments but 7 were given`  in relation to the State app callback.

Comment: I tried to run your code in Colab. It is displayed correctly. At the end, you will get a list of libraries installed in Colab, so please check if there are any differences between your environment and the list.

Comment: Here is the link to the Colab[link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SP-wP1jXTKgtSNcObPZT-0yO5gNk_-dC?usp=sharing)

Comment: Povezava Colab ima nastavljene pravice dostopa, zato jih spremenite tako, da bodo do nje lahko dostopali vsi. Ali to pomeni, da lahko preverim stanje napake?

Comment: Hi, I have given access rights. Please try.

Comment: Colab confirmed. I read the excel file against the df in the data frame at the beginning and overwrite the df. My understanding is that I am being provided with the same data as in Excel, so I have commented out the Excel df. Isn't it the data in the excel file that is causing the error?

Comment: If you access the Colab link now, even without the excel reading there is error.

Comment: You may have gotten an error due to Colab's time limit. I installed Dash with the 1.12.0 specification in response to the error, and confirmed the error in the comments. Please check it out.

Comment: looks like the code I provided to another question - works without issue on my env

Comment: Hi Rob, I was previously running the code on pycharm and worked perfectly. However on jupyter notebook and colab some issues with the callback have occured.

Comment: just debugged in colab,  your dash version is out of date.  need to use 1.20.0

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make the markers of the first scatterplot not be in an upward trend. I.e. have them all along a single horizontal line ideally to remove the appearance of a trend.

Comment: I need sample data to be able to work with that